# How to enable login as root on xrdp with centos and GNOME?

Tags: linux, centos, root, gnome, xrdp

Was wondering if anyone knows how to enable root login on xrdp with GNOME and centos 6?

Below is my config for /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

```
[globals]
bitmap_cache=yes
bitmap_compression=yes
port=3389
crypt_level=high
channel_code=1
max_bpp=24
#black=000000
#grey=d6d3ce
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

Below is my config for /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini:

```
[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3350
EnableUserWindowManager=1
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
DefaultWindowManager=startwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=1
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins

[Sessions]
X11DisplayOffset=10
MaxSessions=10
KillDisconnected=0
IdleTimeLimit=0
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

[Logging]
LogFile=/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=0
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

[X11rdp]
param1=-bs
param2=-nolisten
param3=tcp

[Xvnc]
param1=-bs
param2=-nolisten
param3=tcp
param4=-localhost
param5=-dpi
param6=96
```

Works with a regular user however either root or a user I have given root privileges to won't login.

Before someone says I shouldn't login as root, this is a test environment and I need to be able to.

Cheers

Adam

Comment: Do you mean users with sudo privilege can't login? And why should `root` login to a GUI anyway?

Comment: Yes fixed it now anyway and it was due to the keyboard layout being incorrect by default on xrdp. The English (UK) keyboard layout file is incorrect by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it now anyway and it was due to the keyboard layout being incorrect by default on xrdp. The English (UK) keyboard layout file is incorrect by default.

Follow this for fix:

http://component-parts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/fixing-uk-keyboard-mapping-for-xrdp.html

Comment: I need help please. I was able to install xrdp on Linux and was able to connect using Remote Desktop from Windows 7 to Linux. However, when I login, I get prompt asking me to get root access. I have root access as I can run `sudo su` in terminal. I want to be able to copy files from my Windows local/network to xrdp on Linux to avoid using FileZilla. Appreciate your help to get me started. Please point me to some articles or links. When I copy files from rxdp session, I cannot paste them in my Windows folder. It seems that I need to configure the network. Not sure what to do. Thanks.